# How to save an Illustrator document at a specific PPI and pixel size

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resolution, ppi

In Adobe Illustrator CC 2014 I have designed an illustration with the instructed dimension of 300 × 400 pixels, but I have also been instructed to use 96 PPI instead of 72 PPI for web publishing of this illustration. NOTE:- The company who will publish this illustration on web asked me to send the PNG in 96ppi instead of 72ppi.

I don't see how to set a custom PPI while creating a new document. However, I can change the PPI from document setup after opening the document.

But, saving the PNG at 96 PPI increases the dimension from 300 × 400 pixels to 533 × 400 pixels and saving for web downgrades the PPI from 96 to 72.

I have to submit the final PNG illustration at 96 PPI and dimension 300 × 400 pixels. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Basically whoever instructed you to do this doesn't know what they are talking about. PPI has no affect on how anything is shown on a screen, only pixels matter.

If you absolutely *have* to submit a PNG at 96 PPI, simply...

1. Export from Illustrator at 100% 72 PPI.
2. Open the image in Photoshop.
3. Open the Image Size dialog (*Image → Image Size...*).
4. Uncheck "Resample Image".
5. Change "Resolution" to 96 Pixels/Inch.
6. OK then Save.

Comment: I was thinking that there should be more obvious ways to talk about pixel pitch than using PPI and DPI without causing this sort of mental havoc on people. But then im not a grapghic designer i dont need to design better methods for graphics

Comment: @joojaa it's a futile exercise. It's always going to confuse people no matter what you say or do.

Comment: Yes but atleast one could be clearer than a rather obscure PPI name. I mean if we measured width in say inches and called it optional print width then you woluldn't have all these people trying to set  optional print width for stuff that is never printed. And it would be clear form getgo that its optional and not i mean something that should be enforced.

Comment: @joojaa you should start calling it that! We'd probably lose half our questions if it caught on though :p

Comment: @joojaa Thanks for the answer. I have a doubt though. The software I use has options to change the PPI settings (see screenshot here http://prntscr.com/cce7gi) If PPI has no affect on anything on a screen then why so many predefined options to choose from?

Comment: @Cai - Thanks for the answer. I have the same question for you which I have asked to Jooja in my previous comment.

Comment: @VivekShahi because its easier to just let you put in nonsense just so you can put a checkbox in procedure form than expect you to actually know what you are doing. Either you design for screen and all you care for is pixels or you design for print and do not care about pixels.

Comment: @VivekShahi that affects the resolution of raster effects yes... PPI in and of itself doesn't have an effect *assuming the same pixel size*, but that setting *will change the number of pixels*

Comment: That setting doesn't affect your artwork in general at all anyway, it *only* affects *raster effects*

Comment: @Cai - okay, I am not using any rater effects in my illustration. Does that mean exporting the 72ppi PNG image has no difference when comparing to 96ppi image while both browsing on web(Desktop/Laptop/Mobile{Retina Display})?

Comment: @VivekShahi if the pixel size is exactly the same then the PPI will make no difference, no

Comment: @VivekShahi you can test it. Make a 100x100 pixel image and save it at 72ppi, then make another image that is 100x100 pixels at 300ppi... Open them both and they will look exactly the same

Answer (score 1):

There is no PPI in illustrator! PPI only makes sense for images not a page description language. What size is a pixel in a image that can be shown in a arbitrary size? Size of a pixel is thus arbitrary.

From this follows, that there is no pixel unit in illustrator! This is where the confusion stars as Ilustrator simply defines a pixel 1/72 th of an inch. The alternative solution would just make 100% zoom different in different documents which is more confusing. To really understand this you would need to unlearn 10-50% of your math education.

So you export your image at 72 ppi and change the metadata to say 96ppi. after export. Or dont design with pixel dimensions but physical ones.

**PS**: Just a general observation whenever there is a question here that mentions the words PPI/DPI and pixel in the same sentence you know somebody got it horribly wrong. PPI never really comes to play, unless you print and  having a 300 by 400 pixel image for print makes no sense (except in very very special circumstances where you would not use illustrator).